# Validation fails when using FactoryGirl's sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, factory-bot

I am pretty new to RSpec and FactoryGirl and trying to get my tests passed when using the factories for RSpec.

I have a spec/controllers/shares_controller_spec.rb spec that looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SharesController do
  let(:user) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user
  end

  let(:share) do
    share = FactoryGirl.create(:share)
    share
  end

  context "standard users" do
    it "cannot remove other person's shares" do
      sign_in(:user, user)
      send('delete', 'destroy', :id => share.id)
      response.should redirect_to shares_path
      flash[:alert].should eql('You must be the author to delete this share.')
    end
  end
end
```

and the spec/factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "user-#{n}@qwerty.com"}
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end

  factory :share do
    title "Test"
    content "Test"
    user FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
end
```

When I run

```
rspec spec/controllers/shares_controller_spec.rb
```

my tests are passed, but it somehow breaks the Cucumber:

```
$ rake cucumber:ok
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tasks: TOP => cucumber:ok => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that strike me as strange in your code:

```
let(:user) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user
end

let(:share) do
  share = FactoryGirl.create(:share)
  share
end
```

Why are you assigning `user` and `share` here and then returning them? All you need is:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:share) { FactoryGirl.create(:share) }
```

Also in your factory, you don't need to tell FactoryGirl to create the `user` association, it will do that automatically (see the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage)). So this will do:

```
factory :share do
  title "Test"
  content "Test"
  user
end
```

Since you haven't actually posted your cucumber code it's pretty hard to guess exactly what's happening there, but I'd suggest first changing these things and see if that helps. If not, provide some more info on your cucumber tests and I'll try to offer more suggestions.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! It was not obvious that the user association would be generated automatically - seems like I missed this part in the docs. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. The new FactoryGirl syntax is a bit unintuitive at first but for most basic use cases it simplifies the factory code a lot.